# Debugger pausing at completer.complete(); in firebase_core_web.dart file when initializing firebase (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter

Everytime I initialize firebase with `await Firebase.initializeApp();` my debugger redirects me to `ffirebase_core_web.dart` and pauses at the line (Btw I'm debugging flutter on chrome, cause I dont have an emulator)- `completer.complete()`;

[image]

And this only occurs when I run `await Firebase.initializeApp();`, and doesn't show up other times. What should I do to fix this? Here is my pubspec.yaml-

```
name: messenger_clone
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.5
  firebase_core: 
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.2
  shared_preferences:
  random_string:
  cloud_firestore:


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Here's how I am initializing Firebase-

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pls a screenshot on snippet of how you initialize firebase

Comment: I have edit it!

Comment: Please use "flutter run" on the terminal instead of the debugger. Let see the errors and warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So aparently when you are debugging it in web mode, you need to pass this option in the initializer function-

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: "",
        appId: "",
        messagingSenderId: "",
        projectId: ""),
  );
```

Comment: Worked for me! This is in your main function upon startup. Make sure that your void main() contains "async"!

Comment: void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "API_KEY_HERE",
      appId: "APP_ID_HERE",
      messagingSenderId: "MESSAGE_SENDER_HERE",
      projectId: "PROJECT_ID_HERE",
    ),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}